# Display different info on the Product View page depending on the Category the product belongs to

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm creating a website using Magento 1.9. I have 2 categories (e.g. shoes and clothes). Each product in the categories needs to display a size guide in the product view. But I need to show the correct size guide, which depends on the category the product belongs to

i.e.

- Show the Shoes size guide on the product view when viewing a product that belongs to the shoe category
- And show the Clothes size guide on the product view when viewing a product that belongs to the clothes category

The size guide is a Bootstrap table.

Can someone please tell me how I can display the correct category size guide for a product on the Product View page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.
First fetch a list of all the categories your product belongs to (since your two categories, shoes and clothes, are likely subcategories of your root category, we'll get all of the categories your product belongs to and store them as $categoryIds.

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?> 
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
```

Then we use some simple php logic to decide which set of code to call.
Now check the category ID's of your shoes and clothes categories. Let's say Shoes has the id 5 and clothes has the id 10

```
<div class="sizeguide">
<?php if(in_array(5, $categoryIds)): ?>
// Code for shoes size guide
<?php elseif (in_array(10, $categoryIds)): ?>
// Code for clothes size guide
<?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I'll give that ago.

Answer (score 0):

put your size table in your product description field. it will show automatically.